# can not print Option string using fmt::Display

Tags: rust

I am testing a simple rust code as followed

```
#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize, Debug, Clone)]
struct People {
    name: Option<String>,
    age : usize
}


impl fmt::Display for People {
  fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "({}, {})", Some(self.name), self.age)   
    }
}
```

An error pops up as

> std::option::Optionstd::option::Option<std::string::String>` cannot be formatted with the default formatter

in line of `write!(f, "({}, {})", Some(self.name), self.age)`.

how would I solve it ?

Comment: Don't format it using Display, use Debug instead.

Comment: I.E: `write!(f, "({:?}, {})", self.name, self.age)`

Comment: Besides the point of the question: What version of Rust are you using? That error message implies it was generated by some Rust version before [#73996](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/73996), which was a looong time ago.

Comment: Option represent a possible missing value, ask yourself the question, what print when there is no value ? You need to choice what is your behavior for the two cases

Comment: It's hard to guess your intent, but I don't think `Some(self.name)` will do what you want here, as it results in `Option<Option<String>>`.

Comment: I agree with @justinas - I think this shouts [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Please an expected behavior, like the output you want to see printed.

Comment: @justinas I think the intention of the OP is to assume that the name is `Some` and to print the inner name, handwaving the possibility of it being `None`. I would suggest something like `write!(f, "({}, {})", self.name.as_deref().unwrap_or(""), self.age)`.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `{}` syntax in a format string, it uses the `Display` trait to format the data.  However, `Option` doesn't implement that trait, since `Display` is supposed to represent something typically user-facing, and there isn't necessarily a good representation of that type for `Option` in the general case.

You can use `{:?}` to format things using `Debug`, which will work as long as the interior type also implements `Debug` (which `String` does).  So you could write this:

```
use std::fmt;

#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize, Debug, Clone)]
struct People {
    name: Option<String>,
    age : usize
}


impl fmt::Display for People {
  fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "({:?}, {})", self.name, self.age)   
    }
}
```

If you'd prefer a default value here instead of the name, you can use `unwrap_or` or `unwrap_or_default`:

```
use std::fmt;

#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize, Debug, Clone)]
struct People {
    name: Option<String>,
    age : usize
}

impl fmt::Display for People {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(
            f,
            "({}, {})",
            self.name.as_deref().unwrap_or("Pat Doe"),
            self.age
        )
    }
}
```